# Remove blank page at end of \documentclass{letter}

Tags: page-breaking, document-classes, letters

When Trying to create a letter using the letter document class I get an unwanted blank page at the end of my document. 
It looks like it may be coming from the \begin{letter}{} macro as the first parameter is printed on the final page, but if I remove this parameter I still get a blank page printer. Below is a fairly mwe mostly taken from the sample template for a letter supplied. I have found a better template which I am using but it would still be nice to know what is going on with this template. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% Some of the article customisations are relevant for this class
\name{} % To be used for the return address on the envelope
\signature{My Name} % Goes after the closing (ie at the end of the letter, with space for a signature)
\address{Address of Sender}
% Alternatively, these may be set on an individual basis within each letter environment.

\makelabels % this command prints envelope labels on the final page of the document

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Name and Address of receiver}

\opening{Dear Sir} % eg Hello.

\closing{Sincerely,} % eg Regards,

\cc{} % people this letter is cc-ed to
\encl{} % list of anything enclosed
\ps{} % any post scriptums. ``PS'' labels must be put in manually

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows this issue, please edit this into your question.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I was just in the process of creating one. I've since found a single page "letter" example online called formal_letter_4.tex which seems to work. So I can get by on that for now. Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the call to `\makelabels`, which should print envelope labels at the end of your letter.